# Sharepoint online will support standard view if the list has more than 5000 records

Tags: sharepoint-online

As per Microsoft Sharepoint online will not support standard view if list has more than 5000 records. But In my sharepoint online site I am able to view more than 5000 records through the standard view.

Can anyone clarify what is the actual limit for the standard view?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There can be 30,000,000 items in one list.

Per my test in my sharepoint online environment, we can view the list items in the standard view even if the list items are more than 5000.

But we will get the message as below:

The number of items in this list exceeds the list view threshold, which is 5000 items. Tasks that cause excessive server load (such as those involving all list items) are currently prohibited.

[image]

More reference:

Demystifying the SharePoint List Threshold.

https://en.share-gate.com/blog/demystifying-the-sharepoint-list-thresholds

Comment: This is not a good answer. A list can support up to 30 million items. You just need to plan it carefully with appropriate indexes etc. Google it there is plenty of info. Modern lists will do a form of auto indexing for you based on various criteria. At the moment this may support up 20k (I think) items without your intervention. However I would still recommend careful planning of large lists!

Comment: Yes, we can store more than 5000 items in one list but it will affect SharePoint performance.

Comment: Thank you. We want to use standard view for only exporting the data to excel. I was recommending the datasheet view but there was a problem like user can directly edit the data which might create data problem. Currently my list has more than 7000 rows . So can we use standard view in my list. And will it create performance issue.

Comment: Yes, you can use standard view in your list, but it will affect server load.
When you load all list items, it will take more time.